# Revision page now fails the x-overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I was looking at the revisions for one of the questions, and noticed that the horizontal clipping is broken.

To verify that it wasn't one of my extensions doing so, I opened in an incognito window as well.

### logged in view

[image: logged in]

### guest (incognito) view

[image: guest view]

Link to revisions page: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/252513/revisions

Comment: this seems to be a codereview-only bug that only appears if the "inline" view is selected

Comment: Looks like the code-block formatting isn't properly handled for long lines indeed. Can reproduce.

Comment: I saw this on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65348137/revisions). The sole revision to the post before it was closed was a tag edit. There is one ridiculously long line of code (1622 characters) that may be contributing. The CR post this question links to also has a long code line (only 272 characters).

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed as reported https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361474/235711.

I found this because I had inadvertently made the problem worse.  This did tip me off that I also needed to fix https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/252513/1, though, since it had the same problem despite not showing side-by-side diffs.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this today and had a horrible time trying to see anything. Whilst waiting for SE's fix, here's a script that fixes this for me.
IDK why the code works, but the problem is that the table's `width: 100%` isn't propagating down to the `td`s.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Code Review Fix Overflowing Tables
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/*/revisions
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @description https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10589
// ==/UserScript==


GM_addStyle(`
    #revisions > table > tbody > tr > td {
        max-width: 1px;
    }
`);
```